# How to retrieve a value from the URL?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, url

**My form edit:**

```php
$params = array (
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'my_address_book'
);
$db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $params);

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName LIKE ?', $name2.'%');

while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $flag1 = 1;
    $id = $row['userId'];

    echo '<table width="300px">';
    echo '
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Name</th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td align="left">'.$row["userName"].'</td>
            <td><a href ="Edit?id ="'.$id.'">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    ';
    echo '
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Address1</th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td align="left">'.$row["addressLine1"].'</td>
            <td><a href="Delete?id="'.$row['userId'].'">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    ';
    echo '</table>';
}flag1 = 1;

$id = $row['userId'];
echo '<table width="300px">';
echo '
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Name</th>
        <td>:</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row["userName"].'</td>
        <td><a href ="Edit?id ="'.$id.'">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
';
echo '
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Address1</th>
        <td>:</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row["addressLine1"].'</td>
        <td><a href ="Delete?id="'.$row['userId'].'">Delete </a></td>
    </tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

**In my EditController:**

```php
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost('$id')){
    $form = new Application_Form_Edit1();
    $this->view->form = $form;  
}
```

But it never passes to the "Edit1" form.
I'm really new to Zend. What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a lot of things are wrong and it seems a bit hard to help. What's your form code? (NB! don't use numbers in variable names)

Answer (score 1):

Try `$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')` instead of `$this->getRequest()->isPost('id')`.

```
if (!empty($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))){
    $form = new Application_Form_Edit1();
    $this->view->form = $form;  
}
```

Side Note : Try to go through MVC standards and push your html into views .

Comment: Yes I'd love to.. But I have no Idea how to do that.

Comment: I assumed, your first code block is part of class Application_Form_Edit1. If yes, then html code should be built through Zend_Form component. Try follow [Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html)

Comment: Also for DB part, put all your DB logic into models and call them in your form class. In this way you will no need for put DB params and logic direct inside Form.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
      $data = $this->_request->getPost(); //All your data in $data array. print_r($data) it & you will know.
      $id   = (int)$this->_getParam('id'); // get a variable with name = id
}
```